# Manual resize css attributes

Tags: javascript

The idea is to resize a css definition that has been done in css. The css js object looks as :

```
style: {
    textAlign: "left",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "1.0em",
    lineHeight: "12px",
    fontFamily: "@{fontFamily}",
    color: "@{textColor}",
    margin: "0 10px 0 10px",
    padding: "7px 0 7px 0",
    borderBottom: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
    width: "auto",
    height: "30px",
},
```

Now I would like to zoom all this by a 20% (30px -> 36px, 10px -> 12px, 1.0em -> 1.2em...) . What is the smartest and robust way of doing this ?

Comment: what about `margin ` and `border`

Comment: By zoom you mean increase certain values by some percentage right?

Comment: yes a zoom based on a percentage. Not for the border, yes for the margin. Borders are special..

Comment: What would `"1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)"` become?

Answer (score 1):

Following solution works for values like `1.0em`, `30px` (*number followed by non-numerical value*)

```
Object.keys(styles).forEach( s => {
  if( !isNaN(parseInt(styles[s])) )
  {
     var nonNumericVal = [...(styles[s].match(/[^\d\.]/g, "")|| []) ].join("");
     var numValue = styles[s].replace( nonNumericVal, "");
     if ( !isNaN( numValue ) )
     {
        styles[s] = numValue * 120/100 + nonNumericVal;
     }
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var styles = {
  textAlign: "left",
  fontWeight: "bold",
  fontSize: "1.0em",
  lineHeight: "12px",
  fontFamily: "@{fontFamily}",
  color: "@{textColor}",
  margin: "0 10px 0 10px",
  padding: "7px 0 7px 0",
  borderBottom: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)",
  width: "auto",
  height: "30px",
};

Object.keys(styles).forEach(s => {
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(styles[s]))) {
    var nonNumericVal = [...(styles[s].match(/[^\d\.]/g, "") || [])].join("");
    var numValue = styles[s].replace(nonNumericVal, "");
    if (!isNaN(numValue)) {
      styles[s] = numValue * 120 / 100 + nonNumericVal;
    }
  }
});

console.log(styles);
```

Attributes like (`padding`, `margin`, `background-color`, etc) will require more specific logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS zoom.

```
.zoom {
  zoom: 120%;
}
```

Comment: It could be an option, but it's not valid in the context

Comment: @Charlie H, you can see he didn't add css tag